# How to ask Stata (or any other statistical package) to estimate the R^2 of a user defined linear model?

Tags: regression, stata

Essentially, my task is to take a scatter plot that, under ideal conditions, would have a regression line with a particular slope - say ".5", and come up with some metric of how far off it is from this slope.

My original plan was to compute the scatter plot's actual regression line and compare the coefficient of that model to my "ideal" slope. However, I've realized that this method is prone to be very sensitive to outliers, in the sense that one outlier can totally flip the sign of the coefficient.

Therefore, my thought was to ask Stata to compute the R^2 of a model with slope of .5 -- but I don't know how to do this. Is it possible, in Stata or another package?

Comment: The correlation between a response y and 0.5x is identical to that with x, and so also for squared correlations. Any program which calculates correlations will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In R, with your slope of .5, you could calculate rsquared as

```
rsquared <- (.5 * (sd(x) / sd(y)))^2
```

Here's a simple example where I fit a small model and then use this calculation (and rsquared from both can be compared)

```
x <- c(3, 4, 5, 7, 10)
y <- c(5, 8, 9, 11, 18)
yfit <- lm (y~x)
slope <- yfit$coefficients[2]
slope
rsquaredfit <- summary(yfit)$r.squared
rsquaredfit
# From formula, given slope from fit
rsquared <- (slope * (sd(x) / sd(y)))^2
rsquared
```